# 15 by 15 coordinate finding output

Tags: java, grid, coordinates, discrete-mathematics, map-directions

I've been given a programing task to complete. Find the end coordinate location when given a start point heading north and using simple commands left, right and forward.

A example scenario which was provided is as follows:

Starting input 5,5 RFLFRFLF and the output position the task says to be is 7,7 however I do not get that answer when simply doing it by hand.

Any suggestions in how they got the outcome coordinate to be 7,7

Comment: `RF` and `LF` look like they increase the numbers by one each time; therefore `5,5` -> `7,7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R and L are telling which direction to TURN, not to MOVE.  So going through the example starting at 5,5.

- turn right, now still at 5,5 but facing east.
- move forward, now at 6,5 still facing east
- turn left, now still at 6, 5 but facing north
- move forward, now at 6,6 facing north
- turn right, still at 6,6 facing east
- move forward, now at 7,6 facing east
- turn left, still at 7,6 now facing north
- move forward, now at 7,7.

Comment: Makes sense now appreciate the help

Comment: Can you please accept the answer it it helps.  Thanks!